# Loading keras model with tf function as activation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

So, I trained some models with `tf.cos` as the activation function and saved them with `model.save('name.h5')`. I thought I could just pass `tf.cos` as custom object when loading the model, but that doesn't work.

Trying to load the model without specifying any custom_objects raises this error:

````
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'Dense' using config={'name': 'dense', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 1024, 'activation': {'module': 'builtins', 'class_name': 'function', 'config': 'cos', 'registered_name': 'function'}, 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'GlorotNormal', 'config': {'seed': 42}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}.
Exception encountered: Unknown activation function: 'function'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope. ```
````

I tried passing `{'function':tf.cos}` but then I'll get :

```
Exception encountered: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

perhaps because of the `'config':'cos'`. I don't know how to fix that.

Is there any way I can load these models with custom_objects?

Thanks!

Comment: When you save a model uisng model.save(), it also saves information about the custom objects used in the model. So we need to provide these custom objects when loading the model.

when you load the model pass your custom activation function as your argument.


# load the model with the custom activation function

`load_model=load_model('my_model.h5',custom_objects={'custom_activation':custom_activation})`